# How can I limit azure app service access to specific Google users only?

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, azure-web-app-service

Azure app services provides an authentication/authorization setting for an "azure webapp" -- see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview). However, for all OAUTH authentication providers supported (e.g., Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.) but Microsoft's own AD there's no *authorization* support, just authentication. Once a user is authenticated, he is free to get in. Any way to authorize (once authenticated) access to specific Google users only (without having to write custom code)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, turns out there is a way! You can use place a `web.config` file at the root directory of your site (e.g., `wwwroot`) and use standard IIS web.config syntax. This below is an example of letting just `user1@gmail.com` and `user2@gmail.com` into our website:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You can add and edit the file very easily using the Azure Debug Console at

> http://*your-app-url*.**scm**.azurewebsites.net

.